# get source code of every .js urls in the file

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, http, curl

I have a file called `urls.txt`.

```
https://website.tld/static/main_01.js
https://website.tld/static/main_02.js
https://website.tld/static/main_03.js
....
```

I want every `.js` file source inside `allsource.txt`

**Details:**
open this url in browser `https://website.tld/static/main_01.js`

```
some programming
```

open this url in browser `https://website.tld/static/main_01.js`

```
some more programming
```

open this url in browser `https://website.tld/static/main_01.js`

```
some more more programming
```

so I want this output inside `allsource.txt`

```
some programming
some more programming
some more more programming
```

Comment: Can you add what have you tried so far? Which programming?

Comment: **It Works**
`for i in $(cat url.txt); do (curl -sk $i >> allsource.txt); done`

Comment: Put that in your post/question not here in the comment section please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking to download all the javascript files listed in `urls.txt` and concatenate it in a single file. This `wget` command should work:

```
wget -i urls.txt -O all.js
```

Comment: Thanks for this. please recommend me 
`for i in $(cat urls.txt); do (curl -sk $i >> allsource.txt); done`
or
`wget -i urls.txt -O all.js`

which should i use

Comment: If they both work then it doesn't really matter. Personally I would use the `wget` version as it doesn't require a bash for loop.

Answer (score 0):

`for i in $(cat urls.txt); do (curl -sk $i >> allsource.txt); done`